# With some help, I'm very smart, alone I am quite dumb......

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Just stumbled on this SE a few days ago, and It has inspired me to get into riddles and puzzles myself. This is the second riddle I have ever written, I imagine it should be pretty easy (Though that is easy to say when I wrote it).

I will add hints as time goes on, if I need to. Good luck, have fun, and any feedback is much appreciated.

> With some help, I'm very smart, alone I am quite dumb
>
> My convenience is unrivaled, to my lures you shall succumb
>
> I come in many shapes and sizes, I'm the cause of much debate.
>
> Those who know me well, they love me. The clueless tend to hate.
>
> Ever changing, never ceasing, I won't soon say good-bye,
>
> If you think you know my name then tell me, what am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> Cell phone/smart phone?

With some help, I'm very smart, alone I am quite dumb

> With the help of the internet, you can access any knowledge in the world; by itself it's not super useful if completely isolated

My convenience is unrivaled, to my lures you shall succumb

> It's super convenient to have a phone, you can use it for anything...but it's also distracts a lot of people and is a time waster!

I come in many shapes and sizes, I'm the cause of much debate.

> Phones come in many shapes and sizes, and people debate which phone is best

Those who know me well, they love me. The clueless tend to hate.

> People who use phones a lot love their usefulness; people who don't tend to think it's newfangled technology that gives you cancer

Ever changing, never ceasing, I won't soon say good-bye,

> Phones always change and update (thanks, Moore's Law!) and aren't likely to leave society anytime soon!

If you think you know my name then tell me, what am I?

> Hopefully a cellphone/smartphone!

Comment: Faster, and I think your first line fits better. Well done!

Comment: Well done, both of you. I figured this one would be easy, but I liked the rhyme so I figured I would give it a shot.

Comment: @Cubemaster if this is correct, could you please accept the answer? Just to close the loop! :)

Comment: Whoops, guess I missed this one. My bad

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you are

> A phone

With some help, I'm very smart, alone I am quite dumb

> Smart Phones are personal computers with high-speed access to the internet (other computers), whereas so-called "dumb" phones are not.

My convenience is unrivaled, to my lures you shall succumb

> Most people carry a smartphone everywhere because they are so convenient

I come in many shapes and sizes, I'm the cause of much debate.

> There are many phone manufacturers, and fans tend to defend their favourite models vehemently.

Those who know me well, they love me. The clueless tend to hate.

> Some people who don't easily understand technology dislike the rise of smartphones.

Ever changing, never ceasing, I won't soon say good-bye,

> New models are always coming out, and smartphones are only growing in popularity.

Comment: Great answer yourself! I still like your first line....and it was a close race! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are a **human**

With some help, I'm very smart, alone I am quite dumb

> I know that I don't know anything. ---Socrates

My convenience is unrivaled, to my lures you shall succumb

> True with human

I come in many shapes and sizes, I'm the cause of much debate.

> People can be tall,short,fat,slim, and people quarrel a lot

Those who know me well, they love me. The clueless tend to hate.

> Your friends and your parents love you.

Ever changing, never ceasing, I won't soon say good-bye.

> People live 100 years and much more(oldest man was 256 years ago)